# Transform input and output data with apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have rest web service(post) with this url :http://localhost:9000/employeeservice/employees/

I want to consume this web service but before calling it I want to transform input data(say data coming is json I want to convert it to xml) and also I want to convert response from json to xml.

How can I achieve this with apache camel?

What is from endpoint and to endpoint because I have confusion with this?

Comment: Show us some code. WHat have you tried?